# printing same name, price,and link in BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to Get all Product detail it prints the same things but I want others products to detail also
here is the link from where I want to fetch the data of all product:https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-lifestyle-shoes-13jrmz5e1x6zy7ok

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver


url= "https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-lifestyle-shoes-13jrmz5e1x6zy7ok"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
for n in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')
    content= soup.findAll('div',class_='product-grid')
    content 
    for item in content:
        title= item.find('div',class_ = 'product-card__title').text
        link = item.find('a', {'class': 'product-card__link-overlay'})['href']
        price=item.find('div',class_ ='product-price css-11s12ax is--current-price').text
    print(title,price,link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

1. Their is a wrong indent with your `print`
2. Their is only one element with `class` of `product-grid`

### How to fix?

1. Check the indent of your `print`, it should be in the loop to print the items.
2. Change your selection to:

   ```
   content= soup.find_all('div',class_='product-card')
   ```
3. Bonus: Instead `findAll()` better use the new syntax `find_all()`

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver


url= "https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-lifestyle-shoes-13jrmz5e1x6zy7ok"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
for n in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')
    content= soup.find_all('div',class_='product-card')
    content 
    for item in content:
        title= item.find('div',class_ = 'product-card__title').text
        link = item.find('a', {'class': 'product-card__link-overlay'})['href']
        price=item.find('div',class_ ='product-price css-11s12ax is--current-price').text
        print(title,price,link)
```